# Working with touch listeners and update methods of multiple scenes in AndEngine

Tags: android

I created two scenes with their own touch listener and update threads. I switched to scene 2 from scene 1 using mEngine.setScene(scene2);
This changed the scene. But now touch listener of scene 2 and its update thread is not working. Please tell me how will it work. Also tell what happened to scene 1 is it unloaded or not? If not should it be unloaded if so how?

Thanks

Comment: show your code, when you switch between scenes you don't need to unload anything

Comment: thanks I got the answer. Every thing is to be done in onLoadScene method. It working perfect/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could help :

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/multiple-scenes-vs-activities-t5477.html?hilit=setScene#p24377